# jQuery vertical div slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

In my project I need to do an automatic sliding vertical slider:

```
var number = 0;
var count = $(".home-header-boxes .col-6").children().length;
window.setInterval(
    function() {
        number = number + 104; // 104px div height
        $(".home-header-boxes .col-6 .home-header-boxes-profile-wrapper").each(function(i) {
            $(this).css({
                "transform": "translateY(-" + number + "px)",
            })
        })

        if (number == count * 104) {
            number = 0;
            $(".home-header-boxes .col-6 .home-header-boxes-profile-wrapper").each(function() {
                $(this).css({
                    "transform": "translateY(0px)",
                })
            })
        }
    }, 3000);
```

I wonder if there is a simpler way to do this vertical slider, because sometimes the `transformY` is not going up fluently. It is disappearing and showing.

[Example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9qb12u1u/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the smoothness of the animation.  However, I would simplify the code by introducing another container inside the `.slide-item-wrapper`; that whole container moves up, so that you don't have to animate each `.box-item` separately.  Furthermore, I would eliminate the special case for rewinding the animation to its original position.

```js
var offset = 0;
var count = $(".slide-item-wrapper > * > *").length;
window.setInterval(
  function() {
    offset = (offset - 104) % (count * 104); // 104px div height (incl margin)
    $(".slide-item-wrapper > *").css({
      "transform": "translateY(" + offset + "px)",
    });
  }, 3000);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 100px
}

.slide-item-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 84px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-item-wrapper > * {
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.box-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 84px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-item-wrapper">
  <div>
    <div class="box-item">
      Lipsum
    </div>
     <div class="box-item">
      Lipsum2
    </div>
     <div class="box-item">
      Lipsum3
    </div>
     <div class="box-item">
      Lipsum4
    </div>
     <div class="box-item">
      Lipsum5
    </div>
     <div class="box-item">
      Lipsum6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it works better now. Probably my problem was causing because of animating each box seperately. Thank you very much for your help :)